# ContentProvider is not returning data

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider, cursors

So I have this simple method for getting all words from the dictionary:

```
public static void getFromDictionary(Activity a) {
        System.out.println("Inside getFromDictionary");
        ContentResolver resolver = a
                .getContentResolver();
        String[] projection = new String[] { UserDictionary.Words._ID,
                UserDictionary.Words.WORD, UserDictionary.Words.FREQUENCY };
        Cursor cursor = resolver.query(UserDictionary.Words.CONTENT_URI,
                projection, null, null, null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String word = cursor.getString(1);
            Log.e("DICCIONARIO", word);

        }
    }
```

Well, I tried it in different phones and the while bucle won't enter (there is nothing in the cursor).
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure there are words in the user dictionary?

Comment: I don't know! how do I check? I tried with 3 different phones...

Comment: Go into the Settings on your phone, go to Language & Input, then go to Personal Dictionary.  You can add words there.

Answer (score -1):

Try to limit your projection list by only one item as UserDictionary.Words._ID

or put null as projection parameter